# How to ignore dynamic key when deserialising JSON with jackson

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

I am trying to access the data inside the `X-Amz-Content-Sha256` parameter, but the `X-Amz-Content-Sha256` key is different for each request so I cannot hardcode the key value.

Is there a way to access an object without knowing its key, when using mapper.readValue()?

```
"components": {
    "parameters": {
      "X-Amz-Content-Sha256": {
        "name": "X-Amz-Content-Sha256",
        "in": "header",
        "schema": {
          "type": "string"
        },
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Map` property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize it to `Map`.  Then you can check `Map` key to get desired values.

Sample code to deserialize JSON string to Map:

```
ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(Map.class);

Map<String, Object> jsonMap = reader.readValue(jsonString);
```